# glmmADMB- Pseudo R^2 and residual deviance criteria

Tags: mixed-model, goodness-of-fit, glmm, zero-inflation, deviance

I’ve been using glmmADMB to fit zero-inflated negative binomial models with a random effect (as far as I can tell, this is the only package that will allow me to do this).  I have been trying to do diagnostics of these models, in addition to looking at diagnostic plots.  Here are my specific questions:

1) The residual deviance output seems to be commented out from the summary(glmmADMB) call, as is shown here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/summary.glmm.admb.R?view=markup&root=glmmadmb

Is that correct?  Is there an alternative way to call it?  If not, I have found two other possible ways of calculating this.  Which of the options below would be more appropriate?

```
Option1: sum(residuals(fit, type="pearson")^2) / df.residual(fit)
Option 2:  (100*(Null deviance-Residual deviance)/Null deviance)
```

2) Do you have a suggestion for how to calculate a pseudo-R^2 value from a glmmADMB model?

Comment: I would edit the glmmADMB source to produce whatever you want. But then I wrote ADMB. I have been unable to reliably move changes in glmmADMB into the R package so have given up on that approach.  For example a quick google check on pseudo R^2 shows a number of possibilities.