# Calculate R2 for a GLMM using glmmADMB

Tags: variance, glmm, zero-inflation

I am trying to calculate an R2 value to explain the variance in my model for a GLMM. My model is run using the glmmADMB package in R since the model is zero-inflated and overdispersed.

I have run a full set of models for my ecological data set and have selected my best model based on AICc.

Now that I have my best model, I want to obtain an R2 value for this model. I have tried the following functions: r.squaredGLMM (MuMIn package), sem.model.fits (piecewiseSEM package) and tried the arm package. I have found suggestions to use these packages but they only seem to work with GLMM/lme4 and they will not work with the glmmADMB package.

Does anyone have any suggestions about a function or package that I could use to get this?

Comment: This might be duplicate of this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246973/glmmadmb-pseudo-r2-and-residual-deviance-criteria?rq=1